# Using fwrite with angle brackets and quotation marks

Tags: php, xml, syntax, special-characters, fwrite

I'm creating a form to append data into an XML database, which is being read by a widget on another page. The format that I need the data to be in is as follows:

```
<event start="1914" end="1918" isDuration="true" title="World War I" color="red">
Lots of guns and death.
</event>
```

However, I'm not sure how to do this with PHP's fwrite function because of the use of angle brackets and quotation marks. For example, I tried the following:

```
fwrite($database, <event start="$startdate" end="$enddate" 
isDuration="$isDuration" title="$title" color="$color">
$description
</event>);
```

But this does not work, I get errors about unexpected angle brackets, etc. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You're supposed to give it a string.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

> ***`string`***
>
> The string that is to be written.

Answer (score 0):

```
fwrite($database, "<event start=\"{$startdate}\" end=\"{$enddate}\"  isDuration=\"{$isDuration}\" title=\"{$title}\" color=\"{$color}\"> {$description} </event>");
```